# asp.net MySql MySqlConnection - implement a connection pool or equivalent

Tags: asp.net, mysql

It's my first time of using MySql on ASP.Net.

Unlike MSSql which I use quite often, I've noticed that using MySqlConnection to connect to the db takes ages (I mean a second or two),

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString);
```

Therefore I would like to know how can I implement a connection pool, or whatever recommended structure that could store one connection object (MySqlConnection) to be used across the application.

Is there a common practice for doing so or any other recommendations ?

Here's the code I'm using - maybe I'm doing something wrong here ?

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionString);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    try
    {
      connection.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
     throw (ex);
      }
 }
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT this FROM that", connection);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Is it taking that long for every single attempt?

Comment: Yes. 
Does it mean it shouldn't be like that ?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) it's on by default. Further, you're creating the instance with the connection string, so that's good, because it allows the connector to leverage the pool immediately. So, the fact that it's taking a second or two to create those connections is ***almost certainly*** unrelated to connection pooling and more related to the hardware you're providing MySQL in the environment you're working in.

The term **hardware** is really broad here because you could be dealing with everything from network to disk and memory related issues.

**Do read the documentation** - it does show you how to adjust the connection pooling - so that may help you. I make that statement because your question doesn't give us a lot of information surrounding ***exactly*** how you're using this server or these connections.

Comment: I've update the question above to include a code sample. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with my connection ?